# Search bar for getting data from the database with Next and React

Tags: reactjs, next.js, axios

Okay, first of all, I have send lots of variants of this question, but most of them use some older technology like PhP, jQuery and etc.
I am a junior dev, so I am looking for a way to solve this problem using the tech stack of next, react, redux, axios.
The idea is as follow:
I need a search bar that has two buttons(icons), one for search, other for filter. The user types in the name of a truck or driver, and needs to get back from the database everything that matches his input. So, if i.e you type in "M", it should show you all drivers that have M in their name, all trucks that have the same.
I have not worked much with search queries, so tbh I am very confused about the topic.
Have a look at my component below, it will show you exactly what I mean.

```
'use client'
import React, { ChangeEvent, useState } from 'react';
import SearchIcon from '@/public/icons/applicationIcons/SearchIcon';
import FilterIcon from '@/public/icons/applicationIcons/FilterIcon';
import { useSearchParams, usePathname, useRouter } from 'next/navigation';
import { useDebouncedCallback } from 'use-debounce';
import ArrowLeft from '@/public/icons/vectors/ArrowLeft';

export type SearchProps = {
  onSearch: (value: string) => void
}

const SearchBar = (props: SearchProps) => {
  const { onSearch } = props
  const [value, setValue] = useState('')
  const [isFocused, setIsFocused] = useState(false);
  const searchParams = useSearchParams()
  const pathname = usePathname()
  const { replace } = useRouter()
  console.log(value)

  const handleFocus = () => {
    setIsFocused(true);
  };
  const handleBlur = () => {
    setIsFocused(false)
  }

  const handleSearch = useDebouncedCallback((term: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {

    const { target } = term
    setValue(target.value)
    const params = new URLSearchParams(searchParams)
    if (term) {
      params.set('query', target.value);
    } else {
      params.delete('query');
    }
    replace(`${pathname}?${params.toString()}`);
  }, 300)

  const handleKeyDown = (event: React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    if (event.key === 'Enter') {
      onSearch(value)
    }
  }

  return (
    <div
      className={`flex w-[412px] h-[56px] rounded-full group bg-white hover:bg-[#ededed] ${isFocused || value ? 'bg-[#ece6f0]' : ''
        }`}
    >
      <button onClick={handleBlur} className="p-2">
        {isFocused ? <ArrowLeft /> : <SearchIcon />}
      </button>
      <input
        name='search'
        type="search"
        className={`pl-2 focus:outline-none w-full group-hover:bg-[#ededed] placeholder:text-[#49454F] ${isFocused || value ? 'bg-[#ece6f0]' : ''
          }`}
        placeholder="Caută un vehicul, şofer, număr..."
        value={value}
        onFocus={handleFocus}
        onChange={handleSearch}
        onBlur={handleBlur}
        onKeyDown={handleKeyDown}
      />
      <button className="mr-2 ">
        <FilterIcon />
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SearchBar;
```

As you can see it's a mess. Please advise where I should focus my attention to get the desired results. I am using debounce function here from use-debounce library, so I don't get the changes in params on every change.
The main question is, how do I link it to my backend, so i can retrieve the data?
And also, should I change the logic? Have that component as parent component, and add one child component that will take care of searching logic, and here it will just display it?

I am also having troubles with styling. I used group to have the desired bg style for div and input, but the same approach did not yield any results for focus. So i decided to use local state for that, it's not fully complete, because I haven't committed to it yet, because I believe I am missing some very simple idea of how to do it.